# How do i reverse a string in python using lists and pop()

Tags: python

I am writing a function to take a string and reverse it. I can't work out why my code is returning a reversed string but with only half of the letters of the string passed to it.

```
   def reverse(text):
        temp = []
        reverse_text = ""
        for i in text:
            temp.append(i)
        for i in temp:
            reverse_text += temp.pop()
        print reverse_text
```

Comment: You are modifying the list while you are iterating over it **with a for loop**. This will almost always get you in trouble.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not going to post a complete answer, but:

1. Don't modify a list you're iterating over with a `for` loop. Bad things will happen (you already realized that)
2. You therefore can use a `while` loop to accomplish the task.
3. You can also use a `for` loop, but then you'll end up with `for i in range(len(temp)):` (see other answers), and the `range(len(..))` construct is rather "unpythonic".

Answer (score 1):

```
def reverse(text)
    return text[::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `reversedString = string[::-1]`, most easy way I think.

Comment: Oh wow, they want more code while it could be done so simple? :-(

Comment: yeah.. but someone had to write the code behind [::-1] ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(text)):
    reverse_text += temp.pop()
```

don't change the string.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you are doing pop operation you are changing the temp over which you are iterating as well.

A simple way would be to just do pop n times where n is the length of temp

```
def reverse(text):
    temp = []
    reverse_text = ""
    for i in text:
        temp.append(i)
    print temp
    for i in range(len(temp)):
#         print i, temp[i]
        reverse_text += temp.pop()
    print reverse_text
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't do:

```
text[::-1]
```

Try doing a for loop:

```
text = 'Hello'
product=''
for x in range(len(text)-1, -1, -1):
    product+=text[x]
return product
```